# XML / XSD with namespace

Tags: xml, validation, namespaces, xsd

I have a transformed XML that I've been trying to validate using the XSD it was created from.

The transformed XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ifp:Widget xmlns:ifp="Widget.xsd">
    <ifp:Foo>foo</ifp:Foo>
    <ifp:Bar>bar</ifp:Bar>
 </ifp:Widget>
```

The XSD it was created from (based on raw xml) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
 <xs:element name="Widget">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Foo" type='xs:string'/>
            <xs:element name="Bar" type='xs:string'/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I'm getting an error: 
    cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ifp:Widget'.

Answer (score 1):

Your schema makes no mention of any namespace called `Widget.xsd`. The XML should have no namespaces at all, i.e. just `<Widget>`

Whatever generated that XML needs looking at, it's broken.

I'm guessing `Widget.xsd` is actually the filename of your schema, but that doesn't belong as a namespace declaration in your XML.

Answer (score 0):

To properly have your XML refer to an XSD use something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Widget xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.yourdomain.com Widget.xsd>
    <Foo>foo</Foo>
    <Bar>bar</Bar>
</Widget>
```

If you really needed to define a namespace aliased as "ifp" do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ifp:Widget xmlns:ifp="http://www.yourdomain.com/actualNamespace">
    <ifp:Foo>foo</ifp:Foo>
    <ifp:Bar>bar</ifp:Bar>
</ifp:Widget>
```

You can use both together, of course.

Answer (score 0):

"The XSD it was created from (based on raw xml) is:" is a bit confusing.... From the context it's suggesting that there was an XSD (that you list), from which the XML was generated  but I don't understand what "based on raw xml" means... Are you saying that the XSD was generated from something? Or that the XSD was based on the "raw xml"... In other words, the XSD maybe is supposed to validate the XML used as input into your transformation?

As one more option to add to the already provided answers, here is the XSD that matches your transformed XML; the difference here is that the schema has a target namespace that matches the namespace used by your "transformed XML"...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--W3C Schema generated by QTAssistant/W3C Schema Refactoring Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema xmlns="Widget.xsd" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="Widget.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="Widget">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Foo" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="Bar" type="xsd:string" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

The *string xmlns:ifp="Widget.xsd"* may be right. See [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace): The specification is not entirely prescriptive about the precise rules for namespace names (it does not explicitly say that parsers must reject documents where the namespace name is not a valid Uniform Resource Identifier), and many XML parsers allow any character string to be used.

But no element in your XSD file is in that namespace. Rigth **schema** element in your XSD file:

```
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="Widget.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
```